# Number of 30 min intervals between two timestamps

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Each row of data has a start and end timestamp. I've round them to the nearest 30 min interval using the time_slice function. Now, I would like to calculate the number of 30 min intervals between the start and end (for each row). Is there some kind of inbuilt function for this or do I need to first convert it to epoch/ unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select '01:30'::time as a,
   '13:30'::time as b, 
   timediff('min',a,b) as c, 
   floor(c/30) as d;
```

gives:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01:30:00 | 13:30:00 | 720 | 24 |

so I would use [TIMEDIFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/timediff.html) or DATEDIFF and [FLOOR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/floor.html) the division.